# How to use html data attribute as source of data for ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

I have some data which come from serverside and cannnot be harcoded in js.
I was thinking of rendering them as data attribute in HTML and get that back to angular javascript  but cannot figure how to?

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769732/angular-js-init-ng-model-from-default-values) in stack overflow which suggest to pull data through $http.get('serversideurl'). But I don't want to  make another serverside request again.

Another suggestion was to put the data as global variable (eg somewhere in  in window scope)

I would like to ask if it is possible to pull data directly from html data attribute, which I see convenient at the moment.

Is there any better way to do this? What approach is recommended?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also take a look at the second answer of your linked question https://stackoverflow.com/a/13775151/669561? You could accomplish it via [ngInit](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit)

But the approach I would recommend is fetching the data through an additional HTTP-Request. Is there a technical reason why you don't want to make another server request?

Comment: Thanks for pointing.yes, it is a heavy serverside processing involving external api request, why doing the same job again.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11763263/angularjs-bind-value-into-data-attribute Do you think we can achieve the same like in second answer to above question?